# I Received a strange Bluetooth Connection request from one of my own computers on my network

Tags: bluetooth

I wish I'd taken a screenshot of the connection request, but it basically was asking to connect to my work laptop and I could either accept or reject the request.

The requesting computer is using an older OS (Mojave - because I still use a 32 bit app (a media server that gets its content from a USB dongle) that's not supported in the next major upgrade (Catalina)).

My concern is that maybe that computer has been compromised.  I logged into that computer and poked around, but couldn't see any obvious malfeasance, but then again, I'm not a security expert.  I initiated a reboot as a precaution.

I've seen such bluetooth requests before - but only when I have intentionally tried to connect to another computer to browse files via bluetooth.

I have a firewall up on a UDM (Unifi Dream Machine), so I wasn't too concerned.  Are there reasonable explanations for this random BT request?

*UPDATE*:

I poked around some more in console on the machine the BT request came from and found this log message around the time of the random BT access request:

```
Jul 16 12:16:35 Roberts-Mac-mini bluetoothaudiod[203]: BUG in libdispatch: 18G6032 - 593 - 0x4
```

Could this be evidence indicating the cause of the random request or evidence of a bad actor trying to navigate my network?

Comment: Just for clarity - UDM in this case stands for Ubiquiti Dream Machine or what?

Comment: Yes that's right.